# Is this theorem about girth and bipartite graph wrong?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology, bipartite-graphs

In [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.03904v2), the abstract mentions that the classical work of Andrásfai, Erdős, and Sós implies:

> Every $n$-vertex graph with odd girth $2k+1$ and minimum degree bigger than $\dfrac{2}{2k+1}n$ must be bipartite.

I think the statement is wrong.

My idea is that if G is a graph with odd girth $2k+1$, then it contains an odd cycle (with length $2k+1$). Therefore G is not bipartite, which contradicts to the result of the statement.

Is that statement false? Or did I misunderstand something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is not wrong. It's "saved" by the definition of odd girth: a graph's odd girth is at least $g$ if it contains no odd cycles of length less than $g$. In effect, the classical work showed that graphs with the stipulated minimum degree and *lower bound* on the odd girth must in fact have no odd cycles at all and therefore be bipartite.

Comment: Thanks! It helps me a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

If you look about the middle of page 2, they define "a graph has odd girth at least $g$ if it contains no odd-length cycle of length less than $g$".

In other words they use a concept called "odd girth" which is not the same as saying the girth is odd.

I agree it looks quite confusing though.

Comment: Thanks. I got it!